# Cyclic and Dihedral Groups Homework Assignment

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

My name is David Merlo and I have autism!  I am new to asking questions for homework problems for this website,  so I am looking forward to learning more of solving math homework problems. I am also new at abstract algebra proofs, so these maybe challenging for me unless I get tutoring on the web.  I also have a homework question that I wanted to ask everyone.  This Homework question is from Abstract Algebra homework problems which I couldn't find this homework question from the textbook:

Let $G$ be a group with operation $\diamond$  and let $S$ be a set. Suppose $\Phi : G \to S$ is a
bijection. Define an operation $⋆ : S × S → S$ by
$$
x \star y = \Phi
(\Phi^{−1}(x) \diamond \Phi^{−1}(y))
$$
for all $x, y \in S$.

(a.) Show $S$ is a group with respect to $\star$.
(b.) Show that $\Phi : G \to S$ is an isomorphism.

Thank you so much everyone!  Have a great day!

Best Regards,

David

Comment: Hi David, welcome to the site! Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this question, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you may have.

Comment: Note also that any mathematical expressions should be formatted properly. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) for how the formatting works on this site. I've already made the necessary changes for your question, but for future questions please keep this in mind.

Comment: Start with the definition of a group. The idea is that your bijection $\Phi$ allows you to transfer the structure of $G$ (as a group) to $S$, and so you'll need to use that $G$ is a group. In particular, you're taking elements from $S$, mapping them to their corresponding elements in $G$, performing the operation, and then transferring the result back

Comment: This is great information, Lorago! Thank you so much for helping me with the proof!  I will definitely give your suggestion a try!

Comment: Your posting, at the time of this comment, is very well organized and presented, especially for someone new to MathSE.  The one constructive criticism that I can offer, going forward with your future MathSE postings, is that in general, your postings should show a significant effort on your part to attempt to solve the problem.  Also, it is important to present this attempt in a well organized manner.  ...see next comment

Comment: Normally, in any Math below the level of graduate school, when a problem is assigned from a book/class, the book/class will first provide the Math student with a set of tools, with the understanding that the problem is supposed to be an application of the tools.  Typically, these tools will include previously solved problems, worked examples, &/or established theorems.  So, the first step, in attacking a problem is (often) to *gather your tools*, and try to determine how to apply the tools to attack the problem.  ...see next comment

Comment: When you show (partial) work in a MathSE posting, you may consider including a brief description of the tools that you think are pertinent to the problem.  Then you can show your attempt to use these tools.

Comment: Thank your for your advice regarding that! I will keep that in mind! :)

Comment: @David Thanks for making those changes. As Lorago said, this really comes down to the definition of a group: there is a list of properties that the set $S$ and its operation $\star$ need to satisfy in order for $(S,\star)$ to be a group, and your job is to show that $S$ and $\star$ have these properties. Some "partial work" that would be helpful here would be writing out that list (as it applies to $S$ and $\star$) and/or telling us which of the necessary properties of $(S,\star)$, if any, you were struggling to demonstrate.

Comment: This is called a *transport of structure*.

Comment: Hi Ben!  Yeah, one of properties that I don't understand is the * symbol and how it applies to a group, maybe you can elaborate of what that means, thank you Ben! :)

Comment: Thank you Shaun! I will do more research of a transport of structure proof. :)

Comment: Oboy! I think I finally solve both proofs, one is basically solving basic algebraic proof for showing that a set is a group with respect to an operation, and another proof is basically showing an example from the textbook! Thank you so much everyone! I really appreciate all of your help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial solution.

**Part a:** We wish to show that the set $S$ and its operation $\star:S \times S \to S$ have the properties that define a group structure (AKA the "group axioms"). These properties are

1. **associativity**, that $(x\star y)\star z = x\star (y\star z)$ holds for all $x,y,z \in S$,
2. **the existence of an identity element**, i.e. that there exists an element $1_S \in S$ such that $1_S \star x = x \star 1_S = x$ holds for all $x \in S$, and
3. **the existence of inverses**, i.e. that for every $x \in S$, there exists a corresponding $y \in S$ such that $x \star y = y \star x = 1_S$.

Here is a proof of associativity. Consider any $x,y,z \in S$. We note that
$$
\begin{align}
(x\star y)\star z &= \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(x)\diamond \Phi^{-1}(y)) \star z
\qquad\qquad \qquad \ \ \  \text{(by definition of $\star$)}
\\ & = \Phi\left[\Phi^{-1}[\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(x)\diamond \Phi^{-1}(y))] \diamond \Phi^{-1}(z)\right]
\quad \text{(by definition of $\star$)}
\\ & = \Phi\left[(\Phi^{-1}(x) \diamond \Phi^{-1}(y))\diamond \Phi^{-1}(z)\right]
\qquad \quad\ \ \  \text{(by "canceling" $\Phi^{-1}\circ \Phi$)}
\\ & = \Phi\left[\Phi^{-1}(x) \diamond (\Phi^{-1}(y)\diamond \Phi^{-1}(z))\right] 
\qquad \quad \ \ \  \text{(by associativity of $\diamond$)}
\\ & = \Phi\left[\Phi^{-1}(x) \diamond \Phi^{-1}[\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(y)\diamond \Phi^{-1}(z))]\right]
\\ & = x \star \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(y)\diamond \Phi^{-1}(z))
\\ &= x \star (y \star z).
\end{align}
$$
Here's a proof of the existence of an identity element. We note that because $G,\diamond$ is a group, $G$ must have an identity element, which is to say that there exists an element $1_G \in G$ such that for every $g \in G$, we have $g\diamond 1_G = 1_G \diamond g = g$. Denote $1_S = \Phi(1_G)$. We can see that $1_S$ must be the identity element of $S$. Indeed, for every $x \in S$, we have
\begin{align}
1_S \star x &= \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(x) \diamond \Phi^{-1}(1_S))
\\ & = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(x) \diamond 1_G)
\\ & = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(x))
\\ & = x.
\end{align}
Similarly, we can show that $x\star 1_S = x$.

Now, perhaps you can write a similar proof of the existence of inverses.

**Part b:** In order for $\Phi$ to be an isomorphism, it must be a bijective homomorphism. Since we already know that $\Phi$ is bijective, we only need to show that it is a homomorphism. That is, we must show that for every $g, h \in G$, we have
$$
\Phi(g) \star \Phi(h) = \Phi(g \diamond h).
$$

Comment: Thank you Ben! That would work too! I got a similar answer to part a. The only difference that I got for part b is that I used mapping for the first part, one to one for the second part, onto for the third part, and operation-preserving for the last part to prove that G to S is isomorphic by solving for y=2x, would that also work?

Comment: You've presented the requirements for a map being an isomorphism a little differently than I did, but it sounds like we reached the same conclusion about your first 3 requirements: $\Phi$ is a function from $G$ to $S$, is one to one, and is onto all as a consequence of the information given in the question that $\Phi:G \to S$ is a bijection. I'm not sure what you mean when you say "by solving for $y = 2x$".

Comment: The important and challenging part of part b) is showing that $\Phi$ is operation-preserving

Comment: Hi Ben! That's great that we reach the same conclusion regarding the proof! y=2x is basically an equation tool to show that G to S is either one to one, onto, or showing that G to S is operation-preserving, so I can prove that it is isomorphic. For example, for one to one I show that 2x=2y divides by both sides and we get x=y.

Comment: @David I'm still confused. What does the equation $y = 2x$ have to do with showing that the operator $\Phi$ is operation-preserving?

Comment: You basically use the function from G to S and use that for distributive property for (m+n). Likewise, you substitute the function from G to S to 2 and we get 2(m+n) and is shows that it equals 2m+2n. This example shows that the function of G to S is operation-preserving which proves that G to S is isomorphic.

Comment: @David Are you saying that you're using the function $f(x) = 2x$ to get some kind of intuition about the proof, or are you saying that you are proving the result by showing that it holds in the specific case that the bijection $\Phi$ is the function $\Phi(x) = 2x$?

Comment: Hi Ben! I am proving the result by showing that it holds in the specific case that the bijection is the function 2x.  For instance, I am letting G=(Z,+) which is the set of integers under addition and S=(2Z,+) which is the set of even under addition to prove that G to S is isomorphic.

Comment: Ok, that's not how proofs work in mathematics. Showing that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism in one particular case is not sufficient; the point of a proof is to show that this will always hold no matter what $G,S$ or $\Phi$ specifically are

Comment: Ok, now I understand what that means,  Thank you Ben for the clarifications!  I will see if I can use the textbook example to help me with the proofs!  Have a great and wonderful night!